# For an existing rails application, which is better? building integration tests through cucumber or through selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, bdd

For an existing rails application, which is better? building integration tests through cucumber or through selenium

Answer (score 2):

The two tools serve two different purposes, so you can use them together.

Cucumber is a BDD framework which allows you to phrase scenarios in English then automate them by tying the steps - phrased as Given, When, Then - to matching steps in code.

Those steps can then be used to automate a scenario using the automation tool of your choice. Selenium is an automation tool for web pages, so you could use that if your application is web based.

Answer (score 1):

```
  > which is better?
```

seleinum focuses on testing existing aplictions.
A selenium test is easier to create and may be more difficult to maintain if the gui changes or after renaming items.

cucumber is better for agile/testdriven projects where tests and expected behavior is defined before implementation. cucumber is great for describing new features, that may not exist yet. A customer can see how far the implementation has gone.

Conclusion:

For testdriven/agile development cucumber is better.

For traditional waterfall-style development where tests are written after implementation selenium is better

since you have an existing aplication selenium is the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Which one do you know better? Choose that one.

If you don't have any idea, maybe browsing the cucumber site will be of some use? https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Setting-up-Selenium